# Python - Request not authorized by using requests and json

Tags: python, json, url, request

I've been using code python to access to this kind of url `https://api.elsevier.com/analytics/scival/institution/metrics?metricTypes=ScholarlyOutput&institutionIds=508175%2C508076&yearRange=5yrs&includeSelfCitations=true&byYear=true&includedDocs=AllPublicationTypes&journalImpactType=CiteScore&showAsFieldWeighted=false&apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a`

This is a public json url given by [Elsevier Developer Portal](https://dev.elsevier.com/scival.html#!/SciVal_Institution_Lookup_API/institutionMetrics)

The little code I've been using is this:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.elsevier.com/analytics/scival/institution/metrics?metricTypes=ScholarlyOutput&institutionIds=508175%2C508076&yearRange=5yrs&includeSelfCitations=true&byYear=true&includedDocs=AllPublicationTypes&journalImpactType=CiteScore&showAsFieldWeighted=false&apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a"

with requests.Session() as s:
    data = s.get(url).json()
```

Everything was ok until today that my project gives me error when executing this code, and if i only run  `s.get(url).text` then I get the following message
'Request not authorized. Please specify a valid API key or HMAC signature.'
I have to say that I even have a own api_key and access_token, but even using those I get the same message.

So, I want some help to manage to extract the data, due to the data still is in the link `https://api.elsevier.com/analytics/scival/institution/metrics?metricTypes=ScholarlyOutput&institutionIds=508175%2C508076&yearRange=5yrs&includeSelfCitations=true&byYear=true&includedDocs=AllPublicationTypes&journalImpactType=CiteScore&showAsFieldWeighted=false&apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a` (just google and will see it).
Hope some guide to do this, because until yesterday there were no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the docs and you are missing the header in the request.

The below code is working.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.elsevier.com/analytics/scival/institution/metrics?metricTypes=ScholarlyOutput&institutionIds=508175%2C508076&yearRange=5yrs&includeSelfCitations=true&byYear=true&includedDocs=AllPublicationTypes&journalImpactType=CiteScore&showAsFieldWeighted=false&apiKey=7f59af901d2d86f78a1fd60c1bf9426a"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works well although I still don't know why before it was working fine and today there was error. Can you tell me where did you find the 'types' of headers to pass into request function?

Comment: In the doc they have written the requirement to pass header they have also provided a curl command, I imported the curl command on postman and  converted the postman collection to python.